# How to train tf/keras model with uint8 data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have data that is in the uint8 format. Trying to train a tf/keras model on this data give me the following error:

```
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)
```

Others question here suggest to convert the number into floats; for exemple using:

```
data.astype('float32')
```

However it significantly increase memory usage. Are there way to feed uint8 data to a tf/keras model for training without increasing memory usage ?

Comment: please share minimum reproducible code

Comment: So what is the problem? tf does support uint8

Answer (score 2):

That means that some values in your dataset must be either negative or outside of unsignedInt8 range.

However you can train your model using minimum memory using mixed-precision training.

```
from tensorflow.keras import mixed_precision
mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')
```

what this will do is allow your model to train on float16 precision wherever possible to optimize memory usage. However it only works if your GPU has compute capability of 7.0 or above. More on this at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision

Or you can hard-code it to float16 manually to reduce memory usage.